# How to run a function after stripe checkout was successfully completed React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, vite

I am using react js with vite and I want to run a function after the payment is compleatly done with stripe.
 I know how to redirect to the succesfull page but what I want to do is running a function to upload files to firebase, so this is the code, im using `stripe.redirectToCheckout()`

```js
async function handleCheckout() {
    const stripe = await getStripe();
    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      lineItems: [
        {
          price: import.meta.env.VITE_NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: "payment",
      successUrl: `http://127.0.0.1:5173/BoxPage`,
      cancelUrl: `http://127.0.0.1:5173/BoxPage`,
    });
    if (result.error) {
      // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
      // error, display the localized error message to your customer
      // using `result.error.message`.
    }
  }
```

I tried

```js
if(result) { runMyFunction() }
```

and

```js
stripe.redirectToCheckout({}).then(ans=>console.log(ans).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

But both didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Checkout requires a full redirect to the Checkout page, which means the code on the page that redirects to Checkout will stop running when the redirect happens.

If you want to run code after Checkout is complete you should [set up a Webhook Endpoint and listen for `checkout.session.completed` Events](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) and handle them accordingly.

Also note that [`stripe.redirectToCheckout` is deprecated](https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/redirect_to_checkout) and not recommended.  You should send your customer to [the `url` on the Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url) instead.